# Custom view with model and delegate both accessible from both QML files

Tags: model, qml, qqmlengine, qqmlcontext

*Although I already figured it out, it took quite a while.
If you know a less convoluted solution - please share.*

I'd like to provide a custom `View` that works with any type of `model` (with arbitrarily named fields):

- `model: 3`
- `model: [ "red", "yellow", "green" ]`
- `model: [ {color: "red"}, {color: "yellow"}, {color: "green"} ]`
- `model: ListModel{ ListElement{color: "red"}; ListElement{color: "green"} }`
- subclassed `QAbstractItemModel` and such...

To do that I decided to provide a `property Component delegate` that user would populate with a visual `Item` that would be inserted deep into my `View`.

However, the `View` also needed to access some information from that same `delegate` because otherwise it would either promote unneeded code duplication, or unneeded complexity of proxy `model`.

```js
MyView {
     mymodel: ["red", "blue"]
     mydelegate: Text {
         text: "color=" + modelData.name
         must_also_somehow_set_color_of_MyView_element_to: modelData.color
     }
}
```

...where MyView should be something like:

```js
Column {
    Repeater {
        model: mymodel
        delegate: Rectangle {
            color: somehow_get_color_from_mydelegate
            Text {} // <--- instantiate mydelegate here with data from mymodel
        }
    }
}
```

Doing so seems easy but a naive attempts didn't work. The solution posted as an answer did for me.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that `model` which is visible to `Repeater` or `Instantiator`'s `delegate` contains everything that is visible to said `delegate` including `index` and `modelData`.

Said `model` can be used as a parameter to `ListModel.append()` to create a `ListModel` with a single element.

It can then be assigned as a `model` to a `Repeater` which will load the `delegate` with a copy of all context properties that QML normally derives from the element of `View`'s `model` including `index`, `modelData` and `model` itself.

Upon instantiation, `Repeater`/`Instantiator` fires `onItemAdded`/`onObjectAdded` signal, which can be used as a cue to obtain a reference to the instance of `View`'s `delegate`

User of the `View` can be asked to provide a root `property` in the `delegate` that would store obtained/calculated value which can be used by a `View`

Alternatively, the `View` can contain another `Repeater` or `Instantiator` and request another `delegate` to obtain values it itself needs.
Or a container type can encapsulate both `View`'s data and visual `Item`.

Example:

**MyView.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.1
Column {
    property var mymodel
    property Component mydelegate

    Repeater {
        model: mymodel
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: childrenRect.width; height: childrenRect.height

            //color: model.color //works if "mymodel" has role "color"
            property var myitem: null //this will hold instance of mydelegate
            color: ( null !== myitem
                     && undefined !== myitem.bgcolor ) 
                     ? myitem.bgcolor : "transparent" //reads property of mydelegate

            // <-- mydelegate will be injected here
            Repeater {
                delegate: mydelegate
                model: ListModel{
                    Component.onCompleted: append(model)
                }
                onItemAdded: myitem = item
                onItemRemoved: myitem = null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UsageExamples.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
Window{
    visible: true
    Row {
        spacing: 10

        MyView {
            mymodel: ListModel {
                ListElement{ name: "roses"; color: "red";   }
                ListElement{ name: "violets"; color: "blue";   }
            }
             mydelegate: Text {
                 text: name
                 property color bgcolor: model.color
             }
        }

        MyView {
             mymodel: [{name: "roses", color: "red"}, {name: "violets", color: "blue"}]
             mydelegate: Text {
                 text: modelData.name
                 property color bgcolor: modelData.color
             }
        }

        MyView {
             mymodel: ["red", "blue"]
             mydelegate: Text {
                 text: "color="+modelData
                 property color bgcolor: modelData
             }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your usage of the second Repeater. Maybe a Loader is what you're looking for?

Comment: The usage of second `Repeater` is actually crucial here, as is a second `ListModel` and its function `append()` - it allows `mydelegate` to be exposed to the element of `mymodel` while not actually being instantiated by that `model` itself, i.e. being inside another element. It took me quite a while to figure out how to do it. In other words, it works exactly the same as `Repeater {model:mymodel; delegate:mydelegate}`, except the instantiated `delegate` is wrapped in another `Item` (here - `Rectangle`). And despite trying, I failed to find a way to reparent the element without causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're really looking for a [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) to instantiate the delegate, rather than a second Repeater. You can also simplify a bit by using aliases. Try something like this:

```
Column {
    property alias mymodel: repeater.model
    property Component mydelegate

    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: childrenRect.width; height: childrenRect.height

            color: ( null !== loader.item
                     && undefined !== loader.item.bgcolor ) 
                     ? loader.item.bgcolor : "transparent"

            Loader {
                id: loader
                sourceComponent: myDelegate
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `loader` cannot be reached by the `alias` inside of the root element because `repeater`'s `delegate` is really a `Component` which is loaded with `Loader` "hidden" within the `Repeater`. That makes it impossible to refer to `id` within the `Repeater`'s `delegate` - it's not really an object until `Loader` loads the `Component`, and even then the `id`s are visible only inside the `delegate`. That is the reason why I didn't use alias here. The other property is not aliased because in real code it is actually used in two different `Repeafer`s so it does not make much sense.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear enough, but the main hurdle for me here is to somehow expose the `model` to the `component` in the same way as `Repeater`/`Instantiator` does (or perhaps find another QML-only way to do that?). I.e. pass data from the element of the `model` to the instance of `delegate`. Otherwise what's the point of providing a `delegate` to a `View` if that `View` only makes several copies of the exact same thing? In your example I cannot see how passing `model` data can be accomplished. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're absolutely right about the aliasing the Loader. Sorry for not testing it before I posted. I'll update that part before thinking through your other comment.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Anyway, I reread the docs on `Loader`, specifically `Using a Loader within a View Delegate`. It has an example almost exactly the same as you wrote, specifically stating that this will **not** work. However, it also has solutions for that issue. First one is not for me, and the last one works but is inferior to my `Repeater`-`ListModel`-`append(model)`. But the second one states that moving to another file can somehow help? How and why could it possibly solve anything - isn't it still a different context? If you suggested `Loader` here maybe you know anything about it?

Comment: Please add `property var model2: model` or something similar to the `loader`, otherwise this still makes no sense as a view. Your suggestion does have an advantage - it's faster especially with very large models. But only `model` itself is exposed, so not 100% compatibility with a simple `Repeater`, but this is acceptable.